# Is there a way to increase Azure Event Grid System Topics Deliver operation timeout time?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I am using azure event grid system topic subscription to subscribe the events from storage account (**Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated**) and triggers the function app to copy the blob from one container to another.

And the few blobs are in large size (average 15 Gb). So whenever the new files gets created, the event grid trigger invokes the function app and copies the data to destination. But in large blob scenario the function app runs for longer duration to complete the task (More than 3 minutes), in that case the event grid consider it as timed out deliver operation, retries to deliver the same event again, because of this duplication, another copy has been initiated.

And as per the documentation from azure [Event Grid Retry Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#retry-schedule). After 3 minutes it retry to deliver the event.

So is there any way to increase the event grid system topic's subscription deliver operation timeout?

Diagnostic error message:

```
{ "time": "2023-06-07T12:06:21.2004399Z", "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/MY-SUBSCRIPTION-ID/RESOURCEGROUPS/MY-RESOURCE-GROUP/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.EVENTGRID/SYSTEMTOPICS/MY-TOPIC_NAME", "eventSubscriptionName": "my-event-subscriptions", "category": "DeliveryFailures", "operationName": "Deliver", "message": "outcome=Aborted, latencyInMs=180015, id=fbafd92c-d2c9-4845-a993-d9d6e457ec24, outputEventSystemId=d81de23d-a28d-452a-9ca6-832e8984d36f, state=Filtered, deliveryTime=6/7/2023 12:14:21 PM, deliveryCount=5, probationCount=1, deliverySchema=EventGridEvent, trackedSystemTopicState=CreatedExplicitlyByUser, eventSubscriptionDeliverySchema=EventGridEvent, outputEventFields=InputEvent| EventSubscriptionId| DeliveryTime| DeliveryCount| State| Id| ProbationCount| LastDeliveryOutcome| DeliverySchema| LastDeliveryAttemptTime| SystemId| UseMappedResourceArmIdForBilling| TrackedSystemTopicState, outputEventFieldCount=13, requestExpiration=6/7/2023 12:06:21 PM, delivered=False id=2d5a0090-d01f-000b-3636-990044063809, inputEventSystemId=693d9d67-03c4-4a26-98d5-e79f913f098c publishTime=6/7/2023 11:50:54 AM, eventTime=6/7/2023 11:50:53 AM, eventType=Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated, deliveryTime=1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM, filteringState=FilteringPending, inputSchema=EventGridEvent, publisher=MICROSOFT-STORAGE-STORAGEACCOUNTS.WESTUS-1.EVENTGRID.AZURE.NET, size=1382, subject=/blobServices/default/containers/source-container/blobs/source=agilitek/year=2023/month=06/day=07/set=eloqua.emailsend/uuid=444a11a1-6b29-4952-afac-256269990599/994d4369-5c7c-47b6-ba61-19d26b051965.parquet, inputEventFields=Id| PublishTime| SerializedBody| EventType| Topic| Subject| FilteringHashCode| SystemId| Publisher| FilteringTopic| TopicCategory| DataVersion| MetadataVersion| InputSchema| EventTime| FilteringPolicy, inputEventFieldCount=16, type=AzureFunction, subType=NotApplicable, supportsBatching=False, aadIntegration=False, managedIdentityType=None, armId=/subscriptions/MY-SUBSCRIPTION-ID/resourceGroups/MY-RESOURCE-GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MY-FUNCTION-APP/functions/EventGridTrigger, deliveryResponse=, httpStatusCode=InternalServerError, errorType=UnexpectedError, errorMessage=An unexpected error has occurred. Please report the x-ms-request-id header value to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket., errorMessage=The operation timed out after: 00:03:00"}
```

Note: I have avoided blob trigger for my solution, as it inputs the fileInputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that increasing of timeout is just a workaround, but not the actual solution.

Instead of handling the event directly in this function app, you could use Azure Queue, and one more function app to process queue messages.

Then your 1st function app will receive event from event grid, put it to the queue. Thus, no timeout for event grid will occur.

And your 2nd function app will process message (copy blob) at its own pace.